# Which Ruby gems support the Facebook API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I have a rails application using the Facebook API. I've seen several different Ruby gems for integrating with Facebook, but they look dated.

Is it best to write low-level calls myself? Is there a decent and current gem available?

Have any of these gems changed recently?

---

I'm beginning a new project -- which gem should I use as of September, 2012?

Comment: Consider rephrasing the title to this question so it doesn't seem so subjective.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Koala Gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) is the way to go.

These Railscasts from July will tell you all you need to know about interacting with the Social Graph in Ruby and in Rails (both are **paid** episodes):

[#361: Facebook Graph API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api): *Learn how to use the Facebook Graph API with the Koala gem to fetch data from Facebook and post content through a user. Here I delve into permissions, error handling, and more.*

[#363: Facebook Open Graph](http://railscasts.com/episodes/363-facebook-open-graph): *This episode builds on last week's episodes and shows how to integrate Facebook further through the Open Graph protocol. You will also learn how to tunnel your local server and move Facebook communication into a background process.*

Comment: I'd like to add that though the gem is pretty easy to use, the open graph protocol is a little weird.  it might be worth play with the dev tools on facebook's site to see how to relate objects together. Also, just requests can be so simple just read in the json, e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/zuck  and read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/  (and fun, you can create a ruby facebook app on heroku directly from fb!  see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook-ruby and http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/558/ )

Answer (score 5):

Having used it quite recently, I'd suggest [Koala](http://github.com/arsduo/koala) too. Pretty well documented, goes through the changes in api pretty smoothly, still maintained, and arsduo is a pretty cool guy.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook-ruby),

> With Facebook’s Graph API and the creation of the Open Graph protocol, it is now easier then ever before to read and write data from and to the “social graph”.

...

> The following are proven to work with Ruby 1.9.x and Rails 3.0.0.
>
> **Gems**
>
> [Cardinal Blue’s rest-graph](http://github.com/cardinalblue/rest-graph)
> [miniFB](http://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb)
> [FBGraph](http://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph)
> [Koala](http://github.com/arsduo/koala)
> [Mogli](http://github.com/mmangino/mogli)
>
> **Plugins** - [Facebooker2](http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2)
>
> **Middlewares**
> [OmniAuth](http://github.com/intridea/omniauth)
> [rack-facebook](http://github.com/carlosparamio/rack-facebook)

Answer (score 3):

One known to have an active user base is [facebooker2](http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2). The documentation is not really sufficient right now but its [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker?pli=1) is very active, you get responses pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest either [mogli](http://github.com/mmangino/mogli) or [koala](http://github.com/arsduo/koala).

Answer (score 3):

I've dug into the [Koala](http://github.com/arsduo/koala) deeply for my project, and I found it to be well written, solid code that has full test coverage. The main author, [Alex Koppel](https://github.com/arsduo), definitely knows what he's doing and he cares about the developer community. I needed to make a few improvements, which was easy thanks to the good architecture of the gem, and Alex was helpful in merging the changes into the master branch. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The **oauth2** from Intridea supports Facebook's Graph API.

Blog Post: http://intridea.com/2010/4/22/oauth2-gem-just-in-time-for-facebook-graph?blog=company

On github: http://github.com/intridea/oauth2

Answer (score 1):

The sample source of Heroku's facebook application was used [mogli](https://github.com/mmangino/mogli),but now is [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala).It is the best and great gem.Have a good group -- [koala-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/koala-users)