# Facebook gem for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rubygems

I am going to make a very simple web application. I only need the friend list of the current user and then send a message to a selected user with an image/text. I have looked after gems that wraps the detail of extracting data from Facebook and I found some gems, but they all use the old REST API. First of all: is it bad to use the REST API? If not, is "Facebooker" a good gem? If it is bad I found this [Which Ruby gems support the Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859843/which-ruby-gems-support-the-facebook-social-graph-api) but I don't see much of documentation for the Facebooker2. Are there other options?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i'm using [koala](http://github.com/arsduo/koala) - works with OAuth authentication and Facebook Graph API. Didn't have any serious problems with it, and it's pretty well documented (with examples) on github

Comment: +1 for [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) The only issue we've hit is here: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/issues/110

Comment: I'd go with Koala too. Recently used it and it's up to date and well documented.

Answer (score 3):

The Ruby Toolbox is a great resource for this kind of question.

In your case, try searching for 'facebook' -- as in https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=facebook -- and you'll find that https://github.com/nov/fb_graph is a popular and well-maintained FB gem (at least riight now).

Answer (score 0):

Since Facebook introduced the [Open Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) I've found it's pretty easy to just roll my own wrapper for the REST calls I need using an http client like [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) or [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client). YMMV.